# How to use `ifstream` object in user-defined class?

Tags: c++

I am new in C++ and I have got a problem in using `ifstream` while creating my program. I have defined an `infstream` object in main.cpp as follows:

```
void main() {
string filename;
ifstream inStream;
cout << "Enter name of vector/matrix file (test.txt): ";
cin >> filename;
inStream.open(filename.c_str());
if (!inStream) {
    cout << "Couldn't open inStream";
    exit(1);
}

Vector v1(4);
v1.read(inStream);
}
```

and here comes my question, how can I define the `read()` function in Vector class in order to use the `inStream` object?

```
  class Vector{
  private:
    int length;     
    double * contents; 
  public:
    void read(ifstream in);
  }
```

I try to define it as 
`Vector::read(ifstream inStream)` but fails![image], could anyone give me a hint on this? Thanks so much!

Comment: How does it fail ? What happens ?

Comment: @nos hi Ive added a screenshot of the error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I try to define it as Vector::read(ifstream inStream) but fails, could anyone give me a hint on this? Thanks so much!

There are a few problems to address in your code.

First, the reason it doesn't work is because you pass the object by value. Code should be:

```
class Vector{
private:
    int length;     
    double * contents; 
public:
    void read(ifstream& in); // pass by reference
}
```

Second, this is not a good interface for reading from stream. Consider this instead:

```
class Vector {
    int length;     
    double * contents; 
public:
    friend std::istream& operator<<(std::istream& in, Vector& v);
};
```

Differences:

- you are implementing an operator, not an operation of the vector. This allows you to integrate the reading seamlessly with generic code that uses istream specializations (e.g. you could write: `auto v = boost::lexical_cast<Vector>("serialized representation here");`)
- interface is defined in terms `of std::istream`, `not std::ifstream`. This allows you to use other stream types, as needed (e.g. you could test your code with a std::istringstream instance instead).

If you still need to implement a read function, you should still leave the operator implemented, and implement read like this:

```
void Vector::read(std::istream& in)
{
    in >> *this;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
void read(ifstream in);
```

should be

```
void read(ifstream& in);
```

since `std::ifstream` is **not copyable**. You need to pass it by reference.

Comment: hi @taocp many thanks to your reply! I revised my code and it still implies that declartion is incompatible with my previous declartion in the h.file...

Comment: @Jessica.Jin change the declaration in your header file too